# How to create a data Table or tree to look similar as the picture in primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i develop a web application and i want a similar table like in the picture.

[image: Tabel from MongoVUE]

Can i make a table with jsf2.2 and primefaces 4.0 with a plus button. And when i add on the plus button the documents a visible like in the picture (number 4 in the table).

Or is this impossible with jsf and primefaces and i need another framework. For my work i must work with jsf. So the framework must be compatible with jsf.

The `<p:accordionPanel>` for Primefaces looks not bad. Can i combine this with a `<p:dataTable>`? Or have the `<p:dataTable>` the chance to group table entries with the same doc-Number like in the picture below?

I found this [Link Data Tabel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf;jsessionid=1bd4y1qiimtui1akwwerh4tguf) looks good. 
The Tree looks also good [Link Tree](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeAnimate.jsf;jsessionid=rroijij8ntnt16gxol56ru0na)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same [Tree - Animate](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeAnimate.jsf) example, but modify the `expandedIcon` and `collapsedIcon` of the first `<p:treeNode>` in order to get the plus and minus icons:

```
 <p:tree id="docTree" value="#{documentsController.root}" var="doc" animate="true">  
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-plus"  
                collapsedIcon="ui-icon-minus">  
        <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}"/>  
    </p:treeNode>
 ...
```

[UPDATE]

Or if you want to get a data-table view, you can use [Tree Table](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf), and to get the plus and minus icons, add this to your css:

```
.ui-icon-triangle-1-e {
    background-position: -19px -128px !important;
}

.ui-icon-triangle-1-s {
    background-position: -50px -128px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can i get a data-Table inside the tree to have the columns like in the picture?

Comment: @marius0114 ok, then TreeTable is better for you, I updated the answer to your need

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted

Comment: To use the tree I need TreeNodes. I want to show my data from the database. So i must create for every dokument in my database a tree-node. Correct?

Comment: @marius0114 Correct. Also if you haven't yet, check out the demo page of PrimeFaces tree table and see their `DocumentsController.java` in the demo source.

Comment: Thanks. I check out the demo page. I use a document stored database. I saved the hole document and read every row with key and values out in a class instant. So i must get the tree every row of my document (even one document is store in my root tree) or can i get the hole document and the tree read id out?